# Change with-height cropping with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to change width and height value in Codeigniter upload:

My code:

```
     $config["image_library"] = "gd2";
     $config["source_image"] = $nomedestino;
     $config["width"] = 150;
     $config["height"] = 150;
```

I need to change the value of width-height, using the size that is in the mysql database.

Exemple:

```
     $teste = $this->dbmodel->banner_width();
     $teste2 = $this->dbmodel->banner_height();

     $config["width"] = $teste;
     $config["height"] = $teste2;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: I can not make the width and height value appear here:

$ config ["width"] = $ value1;
$ config ["height"] = $ value2;

Because I want the value to come from the mysql database

Comment: why not? what is the output of `$this->dbmodel->banner_width()`? where is the code for that?